# XML-22003: (Error) Unable to write to output stream

Tags: java, xml, xslt

I am getting XSL Exception "XML-22003: (Error) Unable to write to output stream" while trying to generate XMLs from a XMLStylesheet using Java. The location of the output XML is dynamically defined in the Stylesheet using a parameter set during runtime.
Also, the XML is generated in the location of the stylesheet but I want to get it generated at the specified location only.
I have tried a lot but it seems I am the only person who has got this error.

Below is the snapshot of the **Java code** for setting the location parameter and to process the stylesheet:

```
XSLProcessor processor = new XSLProcessor();
XSLStylesheet xsl =null;

//xslURL is the URL of the Stylesheet stored.
xsl = processor.newXSLStylesheet(xslURL);
Transformer xsltTransformer = xsl.newTransformer();
String filenamePath = finalXMLLocation + "PMTFolder/FinalXMLs/";

xsltTransformer.setParameter("filenamePath","'"+ filenamePath + "'");
xsltTransformer.setParameter("itemCodes", "'" + itemCodes + "'");

//DiagramXML is the location of the XML which has to be transformed.
InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(diagramXML);
StreamSource in = new StreamSource(inputStream);

final StringWriter stringWriter=new StringWriter();
PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(stringWriter);
StreamResult outputTarget=new StreamResult(printWriter);
xsltTransformer.transform(in, outputTarget);
```

Below is the snapshot of the XMLStylesheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"   xmlns:xref="http://www.oracle.com/XSL/Transform/java/oracle.tip.xref.xpath.XRefXPathFunctions" xmlns:xp20="http://www.oracle.com/XSL/Transform/java/oracle.tip.pc.services.functions.Xpath20" xmlns:bpws="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2003/03/business-process/" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:ora="http://schemas.oracle.com/xpath/extension" xmlns:ehdr="http://www.oracle.com/XSL/Transform/java/oracle.tip.esb.server.headers.ESBHeaderFunctions" xmlns:orcl="http://www.oracle.com/XSL/Transform/java/oracle.tip.pc.services.functions.ExtFunc" xmlns:ids="http://xmlns.oracle.com/bpel/services/IdentityService/xpath" xmlns:hwf="http://xmlns.oracle.com/bpel/workflow/xpath"  xmlns:ns7="http://xmlns.oracle.com/EnterpriseObjects/Core/CommonEBO/V1" xmlns:ns8="http://xmlns.oracle.com/EnterpriseObjects/Core/Common/V2"  xmlns:ns1="http://xmlns.oracle.com/EnterpriseObjects/Core/EBO/ItemComposition/V1"  xmlns:prodtool="URI:prodtool" exclude-result-prefixes="xsl xref xp20 bpws ora ehdr orcl ids hwf">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" method="xml" indent="yes" name="xml"/>
    <xsl:param name="filenamePath" value ="c:/code_ws/PMTData/FinalXML"/>

    <xsl:param name="itemCodes"/>
    <xsl:key name="attrModelPath" match="/prodtool:Diagram/pov/attr/atCalcProdAt/AtCalcModPat" use="concat(@productOfferingIdentifier,',',@productOfferingName,',',@productOfferingRelationshipDirection,',',@productOfferingRelationshipType,',',@isRootSalesRelationContext,',',@childProductOfferingIdentifier,',',@childProductOfferingName,',',@productAttributeName,',',@productAttributeDataType)"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:for-each select="/prodtool:Diagram/pov">
            <xsl:if test="not(contains($itemCodes,@primaryIdentifier))">
                <xsl:variable name="filePath" select="concat($filenamePath,concat(concat(concat('ProductOffering_',@primaryIdentifier),'_'),concat(@version,'.xml')))"/>
                <xsl:result-document href="{$filePath}" format="xml">
```

Below is the error I am getting:

```
XSL Exception occured: file:/C:/PMTData/featureSpecification_dpc.xsl<Line 39, Column 57>: XML-22003: (Error) Unable to write to output stream (C:/PMTData/FinalXMLs/FeatureSpecification/FeatureSpecification_C0401116_A.101.xml).
```

Comment: You need to provide some code, so that we can reproduce your error/ understand your use-case.

Comment: I have updated with the code snapshot, stylesheet and the error I am getting. Appreciate if you can have a look.

Comment: Have you tried a `file` URI in the form `file:/C:/PMTData/FinalXMLs/FeatureSpecification/FeatureSpecification_C0401116_A.101.xml` for the `href` attribute instead?

Comment: I tried setting that by changing the parameter to :                    String filenamePath = "file:/c:/PMTData/FinalXMLs/" + tmpIccName + "/"; but getting the same errorfile:/c:/code_ws/PMTData/featureSpecification_dpc.xsl<Line 39, Column 57>: XML-22003: (Error) Unable to write to output stream ('file:/c:/PMTData/FinalXMLs/FeatureSpecification/'FeatureSpecification_C0401116_A.101.xml).

Comment: Does that used XSLT processor manage to write a file to a different location? Perhaps it is an access denied/permission issue. I am afraid I am not familiar with that (Oracle?) processor, the XSLT 2 looks fine.

Comment: I have been trying various hardcoded locations, and finally out of the blue it has started working. I have no idea how.

Comment: @MartinHonnen Actually the servlet hosted on my local server inside which this stylesheet processing was happening was not able to recognize the harcoded location I was giving, and yes it was creating the XML in the location I had stored the stylesheet since this location was inside the server :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been trying various hardcoded locations, and finally out of the blue it has started working. I have no idea how. Definitely the location that I was trying to generate the output XML was a problem. Since I was doing this activity in a Web Project I gave the location of the server (which I tried earlier too but didn't work, maybe I missed something). Now it is able to generate the XML in the server location specified.